# Why inner product on R^n have uniform prototype with symmetric matrix A and positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetry

Details of the problems are given below.
Assume A is a n*n symmetric matrix. Show that any inner product on R^n
has this formula for some symmetric matrix A
with all positive eigenvalues. The formula acts like (x,y)=y$^{\rm T}$Ax, where x and y are vectors in R^n.

Comment: Here's the idea for the symmetry part: consider $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \langle e_j,e_i\rangle$. If $A$ is not symmetric, then this won't hold true. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are not positive, then for an eigenvector $x$ of $A$, $\langle x,x\rangle = x^T Ax = \lambda x^T x < 0$.

Comment: But what I cannot prove is that why the format looks like the transpose of vector x times matrix A times vector x.

Answer (score 1):

This is for linear algebra at U of M, you shouldn't post questions on here, just ask at office hours. I'll give you a hint, though: Consider an arbitrary inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and then use the axioms of an inner product and another special property (all inner products on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are bilinear, meaning they are linear in both arguments of the inner product) to prove the desired result.  Also, you might want to consider the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, because the entries of the matrix $A$ involve this basis.  Good luck!